# How to remove items from a list without the [''] part

Tags: python, list, variables, position

I am trying to get the word "Test" by taking each character out of the list using positions within it.

Here is my code:

```
test1 = ["T", "E", "S", "T"]
one = test1[0:1]
two = test1[1:2]
three = test1[2:3]
four = test1[3:4]

print(one, two, three, four)
```

At the moment my output from the program is:

```
['T'] ['E'] ['S'] ['T']
```

Although that does read "Test" it has [] around each letter which I don't want.

Comment: Take a look at this [`str.join(iterable)` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). You can accomplish what you want with `''.join(test1)`.

Comment: Just use `''.join(test1)` to join the characters. Otherwise, *don't use slices*. Use indices: `test1[0]`.

Comment: @LysandrosNikolaou: wrong way around.

Comment: Haha, just saw it!

Answer (score 1):

`[a:b]` returns a list with every value from index `a` until index `b`.
If you just want to access a singe value from a list you just need to point to the index of the value to access. E.g.

```
s = ['T', 'e', 's', 't']

print(s[0])   # T
print(s[0:1]) # ['T']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using slices of the list not elements. The syntax `l[i1,i2]` returns a list with all elements of `l` between the indices `i1` and `i2`. If one of them is out of bound you get an error. To do what you intended you can do:

```
one = test[0]
two = test[1]
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have *slicing* and *indexing* confused. You are using slicing where you should use indexing.

Slicing always returns a new object of the same type, with the given selection elements. Slicing a list always gives you a list again:

```
>>> test1 = ["T","E","S","T"]
>>> test1[1:3]
['E', 'S']
>>> test1[:1]
['T']
```

while *indexing* uses individual positions only (no `:` colons to separate start and end positions), and gives you the individual elements from the list:

```
>>> test1[0]
'T'
>>> test1[1]
'E'
```

Not that you need to use indexing at all. Use the [`str.join()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) instead; given a separator string, this joins the string elements of a list together with that delimiter in between. Use the empty string:

```
>>> ''.join(test1)
'TEST'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
test1 = ["T","E","S","T"]
final = ""

for i in range(0, len(test1)):
    final = final  + str(test1[i])
```